# Data transfer from node data collection to the browser

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, transfer

I would like to transfer data (var xy) from one javascript file (A.js) to another javascript file (B.js) and visualize that with an index.html.

**A.js**:
Data collection with node.js from json.

**B.js**:
Generating charts/diagrams for visualization based on the data collection from A.js

**index.html**:
Show charts/diagrams from B.js in webbrowser.

What's already working:

- A.js works, if I start the script with "node A.js" in the console.
- B.js/index.html works, if I start with node (express) webserver. Charts/diagrams are in the browser.

But how I have to combine A.js with B.js/index.html? Something like "module.exports.xy"?

**A.js:**

```
var fs = require('collection-json');            //used for read the BELA API information (collection+json)
var underscore = require('underscore');         //used to filter for specific objects (parameters) in the collection
var lookupTable = require('./lookupTable');     //used to have access to the lookup table for the service name of the TM/TC
var _ = require('lodash');                      //is not used yet, but it could be for delivering consistency customization, performance and so on (input from Alain)


var TMTC = "TM";
var dateA = "2013-10-20";
var dateB = "2013-10-22";

var afterDate = "after=" + dateA + "&";
var toDate = "to=" + dateB;
var time = "22:56:26";

console.log("\nAfter date:\t" + dateA);
console.log("To date:\t" + dateB);
console.log("Time:\t\t" + time);

var x_axis_time_stamp_array = new Array();

// Start at the root of our api
var content = fs("http://oberon.unibe.ch/bela-api/v0.0.2/labs/starsim/devices/bela/channels/"+TMTC+"_pus?"+toDate+"T"+time+".000Z", function(error, collection){

    //If no data are available on the server...
    if (error){
        console.log("TM/TC does not exist.");
    }


    //Test---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    console.log(collection._collection.items[0]);
    console.log(collection._collection.items[0].data[0]);
    console.log(
            _.contains(collection._collection.items[0], { name: "hash", value: "e2673ab6", promt: "Hash" })
    );

    var array = collection._collection.items[0];
    console.log(array);
    console.log(
            _.contains(array, { name: "hash", value: "e2673ab6", promt: "Hash" } )
    );
    //Test---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




    var test = ["1", "2", "3"];
    console.log(test);
    console.log(
    _.contains(test, "2")
    );

    //Test---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    //Table legend
    console.log("\nTIME STAMP" + "\t\t\t" + "SERVICE" + " \t" + "SERVICE NAME" + "\t\t" + "SID" + "\n");

    //Iteration over each "data-object" in the "item-collection"
    for (var i = 0; i < collection._collection.items.length; i++) {

        //Time Stamp and fill array
        var time_stamp = collection._collection.items[i].data[1].value;
        x_axis_time_stamp_array[i] = time_stamp; 

        //Service: TM (Service type, Service subtype)
        var service_type = collection._collection.items[i].data[2].value.packet_data_field.data_field_header.service_type;
        var service_subtype = collection._collection.items[i].data[2].value.packet_data_field.data_field_header.service_subtype;
        var service = TMTC + "(" + service_type + "," + service_subtype +")";


        //SID from Application Data in Packet Data Field
        var sid = collection._collection.items[i].data[2].value.packet_data_field.application_data.sid;
        if (sid == undefined){
            sid = "";
        }


        //BELA Mode
//      if (collection._collection.items[i].data[2].value.packet_data_field.application_data.params.hk5 !== undefined) {
//          console.log(collection._collection.items[4].data[2].value.packet_data_field.application_data.params.hk5.bela_mode);
//      }


        //Console Output
        console.log(time_stamp + "\t" + service + " \t" + lookupTable.serviceName[service] + "\t\t" + sid);
    }

});



//provides data to B.js
exports.XY = 5;
```

**B.js:**

```
var input = require('./A.js');
alert('input.XY');

var data1 = [ { x: -1893456000, y: 25868573 }, { x: -1577923200, y: 29662053 }, { x: -1262304000, y: 34427091 }, { x: -946771200, y: 35976777 }, { x: -631152000, y: 39477986 }, { x: -315619200, y: 44677819 }, { x: 0, y: 49040703 }, { x: 315532800, y: 49135283 }, { x: 631152000, y: 50809229 }, { x: 946684800, y: 53594378 }, { x: 1262304000, y: 55317240 } ];
var data2 = [ { x: -1893456000, y: 29888542 }, { x: -1577923200, y: 34019792 }, { x: -1262304000, y: 38594100 }, { x: -946771200, y: 40143332 }, { x: -631152000, y: 44460762 }, { x: -315619200, y: 51619139 }, { x: 0, y: 56571663 }, { x: 315532800, y: 58865670 }, { x: 631152000, y: 59668632 }, { x: 946684800, y: 64392776 }, { x: 1262304000, y: 66927001 } ];
var data3 = [ { x: -1893456000, y: 29389330 }, { x: -1577923200, y: 33125803 }, { x: -1262304000, y: 37857633 }, { x: -946771200, y: 41665901 }, { x: -631152000, y: 47197088 }, { x: -315619200, y: 54973113 }, { x: 0, y: 62795367 }, { x: 315532800, y: 75372362 }, { x: 631152000, y: 85445930 }, { x: 946684800, y: 100236820 }, { x: 1262304000, y: 114555744 } ];

var palette = new Rickshaw.Color.Palette();

var graph1 = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
        element: document.querySelector("#chart-type1"),
        width: 580,
        height: 250,
        series: [ {
            name: "Name of Chart3",
            color: palette.color(),
            data: data1
        } ]
} );

var graph2 = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.querySelector("#chart-type2"),
    width: 580,
    height: 250,
    series: [ {
        name: "Name of Chart3",
        color: palette.color(),
        data: data2
    } ]
} );

var graph3 = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.querySelector("#chart-type3"),
    width: 580,
    height: 250,
    series: [ {
        name: "Name of Chart3",
        color: palette.color(),
        data: data3
    } ]
} );



//Axis Properties

var x_axes = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X( { graph: graph1 } );
var x_axes = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time( { graph: graph2 } );
var x_axes = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time( { graph: graph3 } );

var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
    graph: graph1,
    orientation: 'right',
    tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
    element: document.getElementById('y_axis'),
} );
var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
    graph: graph2,
    orientation: 'right',
    tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
    element: document.getElementById('y_axis'),
} );
var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
    graph: graph3,
    orientation: 'right',
    tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
    element: document.getElementById('y_axis'),
} );



//Chart Rendering

graph1.render();
graph2.render();
graph3.render();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Data_Monitoring</title>


    <!-- Cascading Style Sheets  -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link href="css/rickshaw.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link href="css/envision.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >


</head>
<body>

    <h1>Title</h1>


    <!-- Drawing charts -->
    <div id="chart-type1"></div>
    <div id="chart-type2"></div>
    <div id="chart-type3"></div>


    <!-- JavaScript  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/rickshaw.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/A.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lookupTable.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/B.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, essentially you'll need to export the object or function which returns data from `A.js` and consume that in `B.js`.  Here's a simple example of how to use `modules` [from the Node API](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html):

The contents of `circle.js`:

```
var PI = Math.PI;

exports.area = function (r) {
  return PI * r * r;
};

exports.circumference = function (r) {
  return 2 * PI * r;
};
```

The contents of `foo.js`:

```
var circle = require('./circle.js');
console.log( 'The area of a circle of radius 4 is '
       + circle.area(4));
```

If you need more help in understanding how to use this, please post code samples so that we can further help.

### Update

Here's some example code to hopefully get you started using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/). It's not meant to be complete, but hopefully gives you an idea on how to get started using the two technologies to send information from the server (Node) to the client (browser).

Express API endpoint file (run from Node.js):

```
// This creates a HTTP GET endpoint for your Express app
// which will return the data when a user hits /my-endpoint
app.get("/my-endpoint", function(req, res) {
    // populate the data to return to the client
    var data = {
        XY: 5
    };

    // send the data
    res.send(data);
});
```

Backbone client side code (run from the browser):

```
// This creates a Backbone Model which will hit
// the API endpoint /my-endpoint
var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/my-endpoint"
});

// Create a new instance of the DataModel
var dataModel = new DataModel();

// A function to display the data contained within the dataModel
function displayData() {
    // write the data model to the browser's console
    console.log("dataModel: " + dataModel.toJSON());
}

// when the data model API call is complete, call the displayData function
dataModel.on("sync", displayData);

// fetch() == GET HTTP request to the URL specified in the model
// This will perform the HTTP request to the Express endpoint, and
// once complete, contain the data returned from the API.
// 
// Because we linked this to displayData, that function will be called
// once the fetch is complete.
dataModel.fetch();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reply. As you can see above, I included the code. A.js exports the var "XY" at the end of the code and B.js imports at the beginning of the script. When I start B.js with index.html, the excecution of the code stops at "var input = require(./B.js);"... Everything after this line won't be excecuted. If I include this line at the end of B.js, everything before will be excecuted.

Comment: As a conclusion: everything works except the import of the var "XY". I tried to alert that in the browser, but it doesn't work. :-(

Comment: Correction to my first comment: "var input = require(./A.js);"...instead of B.js

Comment: So based on what I see, you only need to start up node running `B.js` since it will import `A.js` (both need to be within the same directory).  To start up `B.js` you'd need to run `node B.js`.  I'm a bit confused in how the `index.html` is included in this mix.  Node should be running these files, not the browser (so no `alert` but instead a `console.log`).

Comment: That's exactly what confuses me too. The goal is to show the data, collected with node from json file, in the charts, resp. browser. A.js works when I start it in the cmd with "node A.js". On the other hand, the browser shows me the charts generated in B.js. But I would like to show the charts based on the data from A.js. If it helps: I've integrated the index.html code too... I'm glad you try to help me, thanks!

Comment: Okay, I understand. What you want to do is send data from the server side (node) to the client side (browser). In order to do this, you're going to have to do a bit more work. Most of the time this is handled via some API on the server side which sends data over HTTP to the client side. The client makes an HTTP request to an API endpoint, consumes the data, and uses it to populate some template. There are frameworks to handle both sides, or you can write it manually. But what you _can't_ do is just include the javascript file on your client side and have it `require` a node script.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! Hm ok. I just checked the internet and found a framework called "Backbone.js". I will read/learn that to see if this is useful for my "problem". It would be great, if you have some addional hints to this issue too. In any case, thank you for your support!

Comment: Yeah, backbone is a commonly used client side framework. Really all you need is to use its [model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) to make the API request which you'll then inspect to populate your view. On the server side, I'd take a look at [express](http://expressjs.com/) since it's also commonly used. I'll add some general code to the answer above to give you an idea.